# change shortcut to activate a keymap in vim in insert mode

Tags: vim

So I'm currently having the problem of activatig caps-lock during insert mode, exiting insert mode with active capslock and having this nightmare that you are probably familiar with.

So as suggested in [this post](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock), I crated a new keymapping:

in `/home/username/.vim/keymap/insert-only_capslock.vim` you can find:

```
let b:keymap_name = "CAPS"
loadkeymap

a A
b B
c C
...
x X
y Y
z Z

A a 
B b 
C c 
...
X x 
Y y 
Z z
```

and in my `~/.vimrc` you can find:

```
set imsearch=-1
set keymap=insert-only_capslock
set iminsert=0
```

All this code allows my to go into insert mode, type Ctrl-^ and activate capslock and as soon as I exit insert mode, the capslock goes back to normal.

**MY QUESTION =**
how can I change this shortcut Ctrl-^?

I can't find any resource on internet. The only post I found that explains something really basic is [this one](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_make_a_keymap), but it doesn't really cover how to change the shortcut to activate a custom keymap.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'll just point out that with the normal mode
command `gU{motion}` you can change text from lower to upper case (and
`gu{motion}` changes from upper to lower case). I find it pretty handy to just
not worry about case while in insert mode and take care of it once I come back
to normal. :help gu

Comment: If it takes me much longer to find the solution, then yes. I wil try to get used to this "workflow" you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I change this shortcut Ctrl-^?

`:help i_ctrl-^` is a regular insert mode command (not a "shortcut") which can be mapped like any other:

```
inoremap <key> <C-^>
```

It is up to you to decide what key combination to use in place of `<key>`.

Comment: thanks for the "shortcut" correction. So I changed my key combination and the new one is only activating the keymap, it's not deactivating it. I want to use the same key combination to activate AND deactivate. Should I do something else?

Comment: @AfonsoSchulzAlbrecht Perhaps you can use the 'InsertLeave' or the 'InsertLeavePre' autocommand
events to trigger the deactivation of your keymap

Comment: can you please provide the exact commad?